# How To Define The Name For A Module With Only Exports In TypeScript

Tags: typescript, npm

I'm trying to build a whole slew of TypeScript files into a single file to allow for quick browser loading for browser based TDD.  The main index.ts file is located [here](https://github.com/camelCaseDave/xrm-mock/blob/master/src/index.ts) and looks like this

```js
export * from "./xrm-mock/index";
export { XrmMockGenerator } from "./xrm-mock-generator/index";
```

Originally there were two separate libraries, xrm-mock and xrm-mock-generator.  It quickly was determined that there didn't need to be two, and the two libraries where combined using this file.  So far so good.

I was referencing this project from npm, and using [StealJs](https://stealjs.com) to load the files in my unit test using Karma, but it was around 3-6 seconds to load all of the files.  Solution?  Package all the files into a single file.

I used this build script

```
tsc --outFile ./build/build.js --module amd
```

to build a single file, but in it, the name of the root module is being defaulted to index:

```js
define("index", ["require", "exports", "xrm-mock/index", "xrm-mock-generator/index"], function (require, exports, xrmMock, index_1) {
    "use strict";
    Object.defineProperty(exports, "__esModule", { value: true });
    exports.xrmMock = xrmMock;
    exports.XrmMockGenerator = index_1.XrmMockGenerator;
});
```

when I want to default it to "xrm-mock".

Is there a way to get TypeScript to transpile the name as "xrm-mock" instead of index.ts?

If not, what would be the simplest automated method for editing the file (both the "js" and "d.ts"), post build, replacing the "index" with "xrm-mock"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As [the manual states](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/triple-slash-directives.html#-amd-module-), AMD module name can be specified as comment directive:

```
///<amd-module name="xrm-mock"/>
```

Comment: I looked in 3 other spots on Modules, but somehow missed that.  Thanks @estus!